# Hybrid windows and anonymous authentication with .NET 6 Blazor Server App

Tags: c#, blazor, .net-6.0

for the past few years, I've been developing only WPF applications and therefore I'm quite new to Blazor. I'm currently stuck with a problem, and even hours of searching through forums and YouTube haven't helped.

I want to develop a .NET 6 Blazor Server App as an internal company intranet. Windows authentication seems to be a suitable option for this. The Windows authentication works quite well when I enable it on IIS, but only for the entire page.

I've used the MS template for the Blazor Server App and I want, for example, the Index.razor to be accessible to everyone, and when someone clicks on the Counter, the login screen should appear. However, this isn't working for me at all.

If I only enable Windows authentication on IIS, I have to log in when accessing the page, so already on the Index.razor. If I activate anonymous and Windows authentication together, I can access the page, but I don't see the login screen when I click on "Counter". Instead, I only receive a message indicating that I am not authorized. There is no login-pupop like it is when i just use win-auth alone.

Do I have some fundamental misunderstanding here? Is it even possible to do it like this?

Here's some code:

Program.cs

```
...
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
   .AddNegotiate();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default policy.
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});

...

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

...
```

Tried this in Counter.razor:

```
@page "/counter"
@attribute [Authorize]

<PageTitle>Counter</PageTitle>

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p role="status">Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
    }
}
```

and this for testing:

```
@page "/counter"
@attribute [Authorize]

<PageTitle>Counter</PageTitle>

<h1>Counter</h1>

<hr class="my-4" />

<p role="status">Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        <p>authorized!</p>
        <p>logged in as @context.User.Identity?.Name</p>
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        <p>not authorized!</p>
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>

@code {
    p
```